# gfortran compiler 4.4 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, compiler, fortran

We have an old program from 1970 that is verified to work with gfortran-4.4. Is there any way to make it work with Ubuntu 14.04 recommended gfortran 4.8? Are there any major differences and what flags could be changed/added to make gfortran 4.8 work?

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't already know it, the easiest way to run your old Fortran program in Ubuntu 14.04 is to simply install gfortran-4.4. In Ubuntu 14.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran-4.4
```

Description: GNU Fortran 95 compiler
This is the GNU Fortran compiler, which compiles Fortran 95 on platforms supported by the gcc compiler. It uses the gcc backend to generate optimized code.